# ¿Cómo quitar un background de un iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe, background

tengo un proyecto donde coloqué un código que html que saqué de otra página (https://www.gofundme.com/f/hope-for-little-ciro). A la hora de pegarlo arrastra como herencia en su body un background color blanco, el cual no logro quitar. He probado de diversas formas pero no logro comprender la especificidad o como pisar la clase si esta proviene de una url y de un archivo css externo. Les dejo mi html a ver si pueden ayudarme, el iframe está en el div class="gfm-embed"

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/carebro_redes.jpeg">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9b0bb3d5c8.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>DONA AHORA</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark bg-gradient text-white">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img class="logo" src=".//img/cirologo.png" alt="">
                <h1 class="h1_index">Todos con Ciro</h1>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
                    <div class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href=".//index.html">Inicio</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href=".//canavan.html">Canavan</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href="./galeria.html">Galeria</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href=".//contactanos.html">Contactenos</a>
                        <a class="nav-link" href=".//donaahora.html">Dona ahora</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!-- MAIN -->
    <main>
        <div class="donaahora">
            <div class="caja1">
                <h2 class="h2_donaahora">Entre todos podemos ayudar! <h2>
                        <P class="p_donaahora">Es una enfermedad que la padecen 1200 niños en todo el mundo, nuestro
                            proposito es que se conozca
                            y la mision poder ayudar a sustentar los requerimientos basicos que produce esta enfermedad.

                            <div class="gfm-embed"
                                data-url="https://www.gofundme.com/f/hope-for-little-ciro/widget/large/"> </div>
                            <script defer src="https://www.gofundme.com/static/js/embed.js"></script>


                            <div class="icons">
                                <a href="http://paypal.com" target="_blank"><img
                                        src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/paypal.png"></a></th>
                                <a href="http://mercadopago.com" target="_blank"><img
                                        src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mercado-pago.png" /></a></th>
                                <a href="http://visa.com" target="_blank"><img
                                        src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/visa.png"></a>
                                <a href="http://mastercard.com" target="_blank"><img
                                        src="https://img.icons8.com/color/48/000000/mastercard.png" /></a>

                            </div>
            </div>
    </main>
    <!-- FOOTER -->
    <footer class="footer bg-light bg-dark bg-gradient text-white"">
        <div>
            <a href=" http://facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-facebook"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ciro_lovato/" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-instagram"></i></a>
        <a href="http://twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa-brands fa-twitter"></i></a>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
</body>

</html> ``
```

Answer (score 2):

Esto pasa porque por defecto viene ya un script que carga el banner desde otra ruta, solo debes colocar un div y nombrando una id o simplemente agregando un style, le cambias la dimensión horizontalmente para hacer el recuadro a un tamaño que desaparezca el fondo blanco.

Ejemplo:

```
<div style="width: 20rem;">
   <div class="gfm-embed"data-url="https://www.gofundme.com/f/hope-for-little-ciro/widget/large/"></div>
   <script defer src="https://www.gofundme.com/static/js/embed.js"></script>
</div>
```

Luego debes agregarle un flex para colocarlo en el lugar que deseas de la web y listo.

Espero que esto te sirva un saludo.